# JQuery JSON dynamic data for flot chart

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, charts

I am trying to integrate JQuery Flot Chart in my application using example link [here](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/ajax/index.html)

In order to pass the data to `Plot` function I wrote the following action in my controller and it returning JSON result.

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetInvoicePoints(string FromShow, string ToShow)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        DateTime From;
        DateTime To;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(FromShow, out From) && DateTime.TryParse(ToShow, out To))
        {
          foreach (var x in db.res.where(f=>f.date>=FromShow && f.date<=ToShow))
           {
             sb.Append("[" + x.Dt.Month + "," + x.Amt + "],");
           }
        }
     return Json(sb.ToString(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Output result of the above code is `"[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0],[10,0],[11,0],[12,2000.00],"`
The client side I wrote the following code

```
$(function () {
                // jQuery Flot Chart
                var url='@Url.Action("GetInvoicePoints", "Admin")';
                var From="06/06/2013";
                var To = "12/30/2014";                  
                $.getJSON(url, { "FromShow": From, "ToShow": To }, function (responseText) {                        
                    var jsonresponse = responseText.replace(/"/g, '');
                    jsonresponse = "[" + jsonresponse + "]";
                    var  data = [{label: "Paid Subscriptions",
                        data: jsonresponse,
                       lines: {
                           show: true,
                           lineWidth: 1,
                           fill: true,
                           fillColor: {
                               colors: [{
                                   opacity: 0.1
                               }, {
                                   opacity: 0.13
                               }]
                           }
                       },
                       points: {
                           show: true
                       }
                   }];

                    var options = {
                        grid: {
                            hoverable: true
                        },
                        colors: ["#568A89", "#3276B1"],
                        tooltip: true,
                        tooltipOpts: {
                            content: "Value <b>$x</b> Value <span>$y</span>",
                            defaultTheme: false
                        },
                        xaxis: {
                            ticks: [[1, "JAN"], [2, "FEB"], [3, "MAR"], [4, "APR"], [5, "MAY"], [6, "JUN"], [7, "JUL"], [8, "AUG"], [9, "SEP"], [10, "OCT"], [11, "NOV"], [12, "DEC"], [13, "JAN+1"]]
                        },
                        yaxes: {

                        }
                    };

                    var plot3 = $.plot($("#statsChart"), data, options);
                });
```

My problem is the flot chart is displaying correctly for the following hard-coded values at

```
data: [[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0],[10,0],[11,0],[12,2000.00],],
```

but not working for the dynamic values at

```
data: jsonresponse,
```

how to resolve this?

Comment: Why are you adding the bracket in here    jsonresponse = "[" + jsonresponse + "]"; . remove those brackets and then try the asme

Comment: Tried but not working. Actually, it is a series of an Array of Arrays with the X,Y values in the inner array.so that i have added brackets.

Comment: Did you check with using debugger. As the value is coming or not.

Comment: Yeah i have checked with debugger,values are coming correctly from the action url and the result of the action is `"[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0],[10,0],[11,0],[12,2000.00],"`

Comment: it seems that it's just a matter of formatting the returned JsonResult correctly. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you tried the answer, did it helpful to you ?\